# In Jmeter ,from CSV file data is not Reading

Tags: csv, jmeter

Data from CSV file is not reading in jmeter slave system

Please find the below details regarding the issue .

[Thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxDbU.jpg)

[HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6DHk.jpg)

[CSV data set config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrbEa.jpg)

[View Result Tree[][4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui014.jpg)

[csv file :path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJVBb.jpg)

Comment: Does your TestUser.csv present in slave system?

Answer (score 0):

Actually CSV files are not copied automatically in Slave systems, you need to place the CSV required to Slave systems manually as per the path mentioned in CSV Data Set Config element. Use Absolute path.

For more information follow [THIS](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)